# .menu{position:fixed;} fail if overflow exists, why?

Tags: css

This problem is visible only on a cell phone, it does not exist if you load the page using PC.

Even if you use "Inspect" + "Responsive Design" from your browser PC.

My "RWD test template" work fine for BOTH "menu burguer":
"menu in TOP" and "menu in FOOTHER":

https://deliciasnaturales.com/stackoverflow/001_template_without_overflow.php

in this case phone + PC browser = light green!

but when overflow exists (by example from tables):

https://deliciasnaturales.com/stackoverflow/002_template_rwd_with_overflow.php

in this case phone = light RED, PC browser = light green!

then BOTH "menu in TOP" and "menu in FOOTHER"
lost the property `position:fixed`; **why does this happen?**

you can see:
**BOTH pages use 100% identical code**,
unique change is the word:

*template_rwd_without_overflow* vs *template_rwd_with_overflow*

I need the two menus (top + footer) presented all the time (`position:fixed`) independently of height in page.

Is it possible **without the use if JavaScript** nor **jQuery**?

This is the code for both files,
unique difference is the addition of one more cell:

```
<td class="bs1 boram fbl pad05 tc">template_without_overflow</td>
```

then the menus lost the `position:fixed;`

but again:
error only visible from phone, not from PC browser.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      background: #74e63e;
      color: #0f0400;
      font-family: verdana;
      font-size: 0.80em;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #grid_info {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .menu-icon {
      background: #f9e975;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #0f0400;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
      border-right: 1px solid #0f0400;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 2em;
      margin-top: -3px;
      padding-right: 3px;
      /*position:absolute;*/
      position: fixed;
      transition: transform .7s ease;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .menu-icon:before {
      content: '?';
      margin-left: 2px;
      top: -13px;
    }
    
    .menu-icon:after {
      content: '?';
      display: none;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      margin-left: 1px;
    }
    
    #mnutl {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #toggle-menu:checked~label[for="toggle-menu"] .menu-icon {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    
    #toggle-menu:checked~label[for="toggle-menu"] .menu-icon:before {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #toggle-menu:checked~label[for="toggle-menu"] .menu-icon:after {
      display: block;
    }
    
    #toggle-menu:checked+#mnutl {
      display: block;
    }
    
    #toggle-menu {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .mnu_pie_icono {
      background: transparent;
      bottom: -0.03em;
      color: #0f0400;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      transition: transform .4s ease-out;
    }
    
    .mnu_pie_icono:after {
      background: #15ee3d;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      border-top-left-radius: 0.3em;
      bottom: 20em;
      content: '?';
      display: none;
      font-size: 1.6em;
      margin-bottom: 0.33em;
      margin-right: -2px;
      padding-bottom: 0.06em;
      padding-left: 0.1em;
      padding-right: 0.1em;
    }
    
    .mnu_pie_icono:before {
      content: '?';
      font-size: 3.6em;
      margin-right: 0.1em;
      margin-bottom: 3em;
    }
    
    #mnu_pie_enlaces {
      background: gold;
      bottom: 0.7em;
      /* &eacute;ste margen es para el borde inferior del NAV */
      display: none;
      margin-top: 0.02em;
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #mnu_pie_input:checked~label[for="mnu_pie_input"] .mnu_pie_icono {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    
    #mnu_pie_input:checked~label[for="mnu_pie_input"] .mnu_pie_icono:before {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #mnu_pie_input:checked~label[for="mnu_pie_input"] .mnu_pie_icono:after {
      display: block;
    }
    
    #mnu_pie_input:checked+#mnu_pie_enlaces {
      display: block;
    }
    
    #mnu_pie_input {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #mnutl {
      background: tan;
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #pie {
      background: #010105;
      bottom: 0;
      color: #fdfffe;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.65em;
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="icon" href="https://va1a.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>TIT!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cosmos">
    <div id="grid_nkb">
      <div id="grid_nkb_links">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu" class="disn" />
          <nav id="mnutl" class="tc">
            <h1>header MENU OPTIONS</h1>
          </nav><label for="toggle-menu"><span class="menu-icon"></span></label></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grid_info">
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
      <h2 class="tc">info...</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="grid_menu" class="tc"><input type="checkbox" id="mnu_pie_input" class="disn" />
      <div id="mnu_pie_enlaces">
        <h1>foother OPTIONS</h1>
      </div><label for="mnu_pie_input"><span class="mnu_pie_icono"></span></label></div>
  </div>
  <div id="pie">company and credits...</div>
  <table border="1" class="ft ma1 tabos15">
    <tr>
      <td class="bs1 boram fbl pad05 tc">template_without_overflow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bs1 boram fbl pad05 tc">template_without_overflow</td>
      <td class="bs1 boram fbl pad05 tc">template_without_overflow</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: * SECOND link fixed ( https://deliciasnaturales.com/stackoverflow/002_template_rwd_with_overflow.php )

Comment: both pages can be open directly from directory: https://deliciasnaturales.com/stackoverflow but please remember: **error only visible** when open pages using phone, (using BROWSER PC all is fine), please help to fixed the template